# Piping video stream using chroma key with melt

Tags: mlt

I've had excellent results using melt for chroma keying the output of two video files:

```
melt bg.mp4 -track greened.mp4 -filter chroma key=0x00ff0000 variance=0.45 -transition comp
```

Is there a technique for piping the raw output of a camera to the -track argument?

Comment: I have tried the simple expedient of replacing the "greened.mp4" with /dev/video0, in hopes of magic, but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a FFmpeg video4linux2 URL that you know works with ffplay and a simple melt playback command. Don't try anything more complex before ensuring you can simply open and view the camera stream. Walk before running.
See the FAQ for more information:
http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/Questions#How_can_I_capture_audio_and_or_v